# Если макет выглядит следующим образом, то это значит что его нужно делать на всю ширину экрана? Тоесть без контейнера?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Макет выглядит так. Тоесть на нем нет четко выраженного контейнера, т.е мое преположение что он должен выглядеть на всю ширину экрана пользователя?

Comment: Спрашивайте у того, кто делал макет

Comment: да на всю ширину, в ремах и процентах верстать.
а какая ширина макета? если там 1440 то вернуть дизайнеру. Вы же точно не дорисуете до большей ширины что бы оно нормально встало при верстке на весь экран

Comment: разрешение 1920